# How can I split the words in a range to a column?

Tags: split, range, excel-2021

I want the data of the range A2:B6 to be placed inside the column C with the following conditions: non-duplicate, non-empty and sorted.
I have Microsoft Excel 2021.
please help me.

[Screenshot01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHN3x.jpg)

[Myfile](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13fC6fgMNRVkhe6Rd4LdLJ4cxlSF5oJm8/edit?usp=drive_link&ouid=111310305301919035723&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Thank you very much.

I want the split data from a range to one column ascending by name and no duplicate and no empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A2:B6),",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s")))
```

Comment: hi, please could you provide an explanation so that future readers can learn how to fix the issue? thanks!